# Python TypeError: unhashable type: 'weekday'

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a human-friendly string representation for a list of [dateutil.rrule.weekday](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/dateutil/rrule.html#rrule) objects. To this end, I'm trying to create a dictionary `WEEKDAY_TO_NAME` which maps the object to its string representation:

```
import dateutil.parser
from dateutil.rrule import weekdays as WEEKDAYS
WEEKDAY_NAMES = [name[1] for name in dateutil.parser.parserinfo.WEEKDAYS]

WEEKDAY_TO_NAME = dict(zip(WEEKDAYS, WEEKDAY_NAMES))
```

However, this leads to a

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'weekday'
```

Is there any way to get around this (without writing seven `if`/`elif` statements)?

Comment: When does the error occur and what Python version are you using? I'm using `Python2.7` and I'm unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Agree with @JoséSánchez works fine in 2.7

Comment: But not in Python-3.x. `hash(WEEKDAYS[0])` does not work.

Comment: What version of `dateutil` are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, you need to convert the items in `WEEKDAYS` to strings:

```
>>> dict(zip(map(str,WEEKDAYS), WEEKDAY_NAMES))
{'SA': 'Saturday', 'TH': 'Thursday', 'SU': 'Sunday', 'WE': 'Wednesday', 'TU': 'Tuesday', 'MO': 'Monday', 'FR': 'Friday'}
```

Note the `type()` of item in `WEEKDAYS` before conversion is `'dateutil.rrule.weekday'`:

```
>>> [type(item) for item in WEEKDAYS]
[<class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>, <class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>, <class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>, <class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>, <class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>, <class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>, <class 'dateutil.rrule.weekday'>]
```

(Thanks to hascode55 and MSeifert for pointing out that the `tuple()` calls I had before were unnecessary.)

Comment: `dict(zip(map(str,WEEKDAYS), WEEKDAY_NAMES))` - this'd work

Comment: Why all these `tuple`s? Wouldn't it also work without them?

Answer (score 0):

I should have perhaps been more clear about what I wanted to achieve: a function `weekday_to_string` which takes an instance of `dateutil.rrule.weekday` as input and returns a string such as "Monday". I wanted to use the dictionary as a lookup table inside this function, so it actually would not do to convert the `dateutil.rrule.weekday` instances to strings first since then I would not be able to look up the input anymore.

Here is how I implemented it in the end:

```
def weekday_to_string(weekday):
    '''Converts a dateutil.rrule weekday constant to its full string representation.'''
    WEEKDAY_NAMES = [name[1] for name in dateutil.parser.parserinfo.WEEKDAYS]
    return WEEKDAY_NAMES[WEEKDAYS.index(weekday)]
```